# How to get list of devices connected to my Wi-Fi in android?

Tags: android, wifip2p, nsd

I need to get the list of devices (and possible details of them as well) that are connected to the Wi-Fi which is I have connected to. I don't need to connect and chat with any of them. I'm going through this link http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#fetch.

Is wifi p2p connection works for my requirement? How do I get the list of connected devices on the device with no Wifi-Direct feature? Do my app needs to be installed on other devices in order to use wifi p2p connection? I have tried this https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery but it is force closing on launch of app. I've seen same kind of apps on playstore like [Fing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en). How did they do this?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: me too looking for the same..

Comment: i did not find any other library so fixed that errors and now i am using this library for my project

Answer (score 0):

```
    manager=(WifiP2pManager)getSystemService(WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    channel=manager.initialize(this, Looper.getMainLooper(),null);
```

When PEERS CHANGE.. call..

```
    manager.requestPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList wifiP2pDeviceList) {
            Log.e("peer num", "" + wifiP2pDeviceList.getDeviceList().size());
            devices.clear();
            devices.addAll(wifiP2pDeviceList.getDeviceList());


            for(WifiP2pDevice device:wifiP2pDeviceList.getDeviceList()){
                //Log.e("device ",device.toString());
                dnames.clear();
                daddresses.clear();
                dnames.add(device.deviceName);
                daddresses.add(device.deviceAddress);
            }

        }
    });
```